# Object gets copied, but i want the original

Tags: javascript, object, reference, copy

I have some global vars, which I know, bad code and all.
One of these vars: MyApp.player.pet, is an object of type pet, attached to the player object. It has some properties like "xp" which is just a number.

I am passing this object to a dynamic UI class that displays information about all kinds of objects, which is why I can't use the reference to the global var inside the object. Here is how I pass it:

```
 var listOfProperties =
        [MyApp.player.pet.name,
        {"xp: ": MyApp.player.pet.xp},
        {"xpToNextLevel: " :  MyApp.player.pet.xpToNextLevel}];
```

then I transfer this list of properties to a new UI object as such:

```
new tooltipText(listOfProperties, ..., ...)
```

However, when the value gets updated inside MyApp.player.pet.xp the value inside the object tooltipText doesn't change. Somehow it's passing a copy, but I want to pass a reference if those are correct terms.

I've tried searching for this but all I can find are people asking how to make copies of objects, which seems to be what I've done unintentionally but not what I want.

How can I make sure that when MyApp.player.pet.xp changes, the value inside the tooltiptext also changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some misconception in your question:

- You did not create copies of your original objects.
- You merely copied some of their property **values**, by putting them into new objects (e.g. `{"xp: ": MyApp.player.pet.xp}`).

If you want to change the properties of your original objects, you need to change them there, not in your newly created small objects.

So if you want a generic list of properties, you need to keep a reference to your original object (`MyApp.player.pet`) as well. Example:

```
var listOfProperties = {
  obj: MyApp.player.pet,
  propertyNames: ['xp', 'xpToNextLevel']
}
```

You can then use the property names to generically set the properties of your original object:

```
var propertyName = listOfProperties.propertyNames[0];
listOfProperties.obj[propertyName] = newValue;
```

Comment: Of course! It hadn't occurred to me that i was only passing the value. Now that you mentioned it, it makes perfect sense, i'll just pass the object. Thanks.